Removing rows from a dataframe based on a condition in Pandas but keep duplicates
This is a very unique requirement and I need some help. This is not removing duplicates from a csv.
I have rows of data and I want to remove rows based on a condition like below example.
Input file:
item,location,po#,qty,price
1,SF,100,2,1.0
2,PH,123,3,1.0
1,SF,101,2,1.0
1,SF,100,2,1.0
3,AL,100,3,4.0

output file:
item,location,po#,qty,price
1,SF,100,2,1.0
2,PH,123,3,1.0
1,SF,100,2,1.0
3,AL,100,3,4.0

Here I remove below line because this is the next po# and means earlier has been processed already and processing this again will cause double processing.
1,SF,101,2,1.0

but I  need to keep below row although it looks like  duplicate
1,SF,100,2,1.0

because this means that the PO has been split into two parts and needs to be processed.
I tried drop_duplicates function of pandas over subset rows. but it seems more like a logic problem than a coding problem. Maybe I  need to break this process into multiple steps but I cant put my finger on it yet and need some guidance.

Your description makes no sense to me.  Why would you remove "SF,101" but keep the duplicate "SF,100"?  It seems like that's exactly backwards.  If you have a new PO number, then why would you assume it has already been processed?

101 means 100 became void and 101 was created for it. If i process both 100 and 101 I clear twice the actual qty.
2 PO with 100 means PO qty was split between them and I need to process them both . I know its weird but that is the requirement unfortunately.

So, wouldn't you always want to handle the largest PO # for a given item number?
